# Why am I still getting full depth json responces from my controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

I have a Asp.Net Core API *v5.0.7*. The client is a ReactJs.Net app.

All my controllers are marked with:

```cs
[Consumes("application/json")]
[Produces("application/json")]
```

My Startup.cs file `ConfigureServices` method contains:

```cs
services.AddControllers()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => { 
                    options.SerializerSettings.MaxDepth = 2;
                    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                });
```

But I am still getting my json back with full depth:

```json
[
    {
        "itemNumber": "11BRC",
        "itemDescription": "Flat head Phillips Wood screw C-Pak 2x1/4",
        "featured": false,
        "categoryName": "Screws",
        "category": {
            "categoryId": 1003,
            "parentId": 3056,
            "name": "Screws",
            "parent": {
                "categoryId": 3056,
                "parentId": 0,
                "name": "Fasteners",
                "parent": null,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "categoryId": 3036,
                        "parentId": 3056,
                        "name": "Nuts",
                        "children": null,
                        "title": "Nuts",
                        "description": "Fastener Nuts",
                        "keywords": " Anchor, cage, classic, clinch, castle,nuts",
                        "pageContent": "<span style=\"font-style:italic; font-weight:bold; font-size:16pt;\"><span style=\"color:Blue; border-color:Blue; font-style:normal;\">NUTS</span><br/>Nuts and bolts are among the most expansive categories of hardware</span>. <br/>Options run the gamut, with coupling, locking, flanged, hex, square and more. We offer numerous material, finish and size options. When it comes to industrial nuts and bolts, <br/><span style=\"color:Navy; border-color:Navy; font-weight:bold;\">Fastener Superstore has a comprehensive selection for your manufacturing or assembly needs. We provide products in bulk so that your business is stocked with reliable, well made fasteners. When it comes to the hardware you use, it always pays to do business with the best.</span>",
                        "bannerGroupId": 0,
                        "inactive": 0,
                        "issitecategory": 0,
...
```

Do I need to add `[JsonIgnore]` to my navigation properties?

Comment: You need to *not* reuse the same classes for both the data layer and the response model, and write queries that return only the data you really need. `SerializerSettings.MaxDepth` isn't a cheap way to map between entities and DTOs. If anything, you're loading all those `Children` rows without even sending them to the client. The JSON serialization setting affect how the results are serialized to JSON, not the query itself.

Comment: What does your code look like? EF Core will use lazy loading to load related entities. `Children` should be empty unless `.Include()` is used, or the children were loaded explicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: I flattened everything with AutoMapper to a dto